# Summarizing and Rank in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I hav a set of data with the following columns:    Date, Teacher_Name, Class, Student_Name, Attendance.

Attendance parameter:
2-Full attendance
1-Leave half way
0-No show

I would like to have a visual with the following:

Top 5 students with most "No show" for latest 3 consecutive weeks by Teacher

Week grouped by Sat-Fri

Please advise on how I can do this in Power BI

Answer (score 0):

Create a measure along the lines of:

```
NoShows = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Students), FILTER(Students, Attendance = "No Show"))
```

Then lay out your visual using the rest of the filters you mention and set a TopN filter on the report.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Let me rephrase. I need them to be grouped by week then rank to find the top 5  no show of the week. Then list out those with consecutive no show for the latest 3 weeks

Comment: I believe if your visual is grouped correctly and the filter on the measure is applied correctly then Top N should work.